# Local storage keys in Firefox return different empty value than other browsers

Tags: html, firefox, local-storage

Firefox and Chrome return different values when accessing local storage via a key.

```
alert(localStorage.mykey); // FF = null, Chrome = undefined
alert(localStorage.getItem('mykey')); // FF = null, Chrome = null
```

See Firefox bug [localStorage/sessionStorage should return undefined (not null) for undefined keys.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=532062)

Essentially, Chrome and other browsers treat `localStorage.mykey` like any other array object where Firefox treats it like `getItem()`.

So, my question is: Given this discrepancy, what is the best way to check if a key exists in localStorage?

Option 1: `if(localStorage.getItem('key') === null)`

Option 2: `if(localStorage.key === null || localStorage.key === undefined)`

Option 3: Any way to check localStorage.key without the `||` in #2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Firefox were you using? Recent versions (I tested using Firefox 14) return `undefined` in this case. Anyway, the easy test is `typeof localStorage.key == "string"`.

Comment: I was using FF v12. I don't use it as my primary browser so I hadn't updated in a long time. Thanks for bringing that up. Just updated to FF v16.